# Apache Camel (Talend SOA Suite) vs Oracle Service Bus and Oracle SOA Suite

Tags: apache-camel

Any body is using Talend SOA Suite in their shop.
How does it compare with Oracle SOA Suite and Service Bus as both these products implement the EIP patterns if i am not wrong ?

Currently i am trying to study both but i am leaning towards Apache Camel and Talend Suite but is there anything that Oracle SOA suite and Oracle Service Bus provides that is over and above what Talend SOA suite does not.

Am i missing the bigger picture here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my perspective, using the Oracle SOA/ESB Suite is a whole different ballgame in terms of feature scope, complexity, learning curve, price (obviously) and overall commitment to the Oracle stack...

Apache Camel is focused on a small subset of that...mainly EIPs to implement complex routing and components to ease integration with other technologies...that's it.  Its not an ESB (see ServiceMix for that) or a container of any kind.  Instead, its designed to be lightweight and easily embeddable in existing applications (Tomcat web apps, ActiveMQ, ServiceMix, standalone with Spring, etc).  Overall, if you know Java, Maven & Spring, then you can get things up and running in literally minutes.

Camel also has a strong community following and has been embraced (along with ActiveMQ, Servicemix, CXF & Karaf) by a growing number of companies both large and small.

(full disclosure - I'm an Apache SOA Consultant, but I have some experience with the Weblogic stack as well)

Comment: Boday Thanks a lot for taking timeout and answering this.

Answer (score 6):

Talend does offer a full ESB.  That ESB use Apache CXF for SOAP and REST, Apache ActiveMQ for JMS, and Apache Camel for mediation and routing.  Those three modules are provided in distribution that includes Apache Karaf.  Karaf is an OSGI container.  However, as boday pointed out you can run any or all of these components inside a Servlet, Java EE, or even a simple JVM instead if you prefer.

So that is the first difference, Talend is much more lighweight and *modular*.  That modularity is much deeper than simple compliance to Java EE APIs.  You can pick and choose whether you want CXF, ActiveMQ, or which Camel components in particular to include.  If you opt for the Karaf / OSGI option you get to leverage the power of OSGI bundle management.  This may not seem important at first glance, but it is quite important in an enterprise context.

OSGI manages dependencies at the *package* (rather than the jar) level.  It is the same standard used by your Eclipse IDE.  When you install a feature package from Eclipse Marketplace (e.g. subclipse) you are using OSGI feature management.  That is why Talend include Apache Karaf in the distribution.  So that you have the same pluggable, modular framework for both deployment and dependency management for your enterprise applications.

Why is that important?  Because when you have different application teams deploying apps in the enterprise, you need a little bit of flex in your bus.  You need to do a few transformations, a little bit of message correlation, use a few EIP's like idempotent consumer.  Well all those transforms may need to act on the message payload or use jars provided by the project teams authoring the apps that are being integrated.  And all those project teams are on different lifecycles.  This is what Microsoft calls DLL hell, and that is why the invented .NET assemblies.  Java does not have an equivalent feature that is part of the JCP.  But there is a very mature *standard* that addresses this.  That is OSGI.  The open source engine that realizes OSGI is Equinox in Eclipse, or Apache Felix.  Both are are pluggable in the Karaf container.

So much for the container, what about the heart of the ESB, Apache Camel.  I'm sure most readers are aware, but Camel realizes the [enterprise integration patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/) (EIP) from the Gregor Hohpe and Bobby Woolf book of the same name.  It is just a library, and it can run in any jvm, and in fact with or without DI container such as Spring.  The important thing to take away is that Camel addresses the need for asynchronous, event driven integration which is necessary to address the [fallacies of distributed computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_Distributed_Computing).  And it does it in a completely flexible way that does not *require* you to deploy Java EE servers everywhere.  Want to have a dedicated integration server, great use Talend ESB out-of-the-box for an OSGI server.  Want to service enable managed endpoints inside Tomcat, great, deploy Camel, CXF, and ActiveMQ inside Tomcat if you like.  You get much greater, platform agnostic and architecture agility with a lightweight modular integration platform like Talend.

Another differentiator worth mentioning is that transformations are one of those mundane things that are still really important.  You need to really think about how you plan to manage the schemas of the messages and events that are being placed on the bus.  Talend ESB provides transformation tools OTB.

(full disclosure - I am Technical director at Talend, but I hope that I have emphasized the Apache and OSS aspects here in a very objective manner.)

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. I have a question: I am developing a web service with spring and CXF in my web application, how can I deploy my web service into the talend ESB? Or I just deploy my web application to my own JavaEE application server, then make a proxy in ESB to route my messages to another application, right?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Camel is an integration framework. Talend and Oracle are ESB products respectively integration suites. Find a detailed description, comparison and recommendation  when to use which one in my presentation slides: "[Spoilt for Choice - How to choose the right Enterprise Service Bus](http://www.kai-waehner.de/blog/2013/01/23/spoilt-for-choice-how-to-choose-the-right-enterprise-service-bus-esb/)"

(not just interesting for Talend and Oracle, but also for IBM, SAP, Spring Integration, Mule ESB, Fuse ESB, WSO2, and other integration frameworks / ESBs / integration suites)

[Like Ed, I also work for Talend, but this is a vendor-neutral presentation]